autoinstall 24.04 desktop
I have a single machine desktop environment where I am runnng 24.04. There is nothing involved from the cloud. I have designed my system so that I can re-install Ubuntu without losing anything. This means that it becomes simple to recover from system data corruption. I currently replace the contents of my old system partition completely using the installer manual storage configurator option.
I am looking at autoinstall as currently, the actual installation of a new copy of Ubuntu is done manually and I want to automate this part of the process. I am having problems understanding how autoinstall works in this environment and I have been unable to find anything that completely describes the contents of the yaml file used by autoinstall, only tutorials which are normally not complete.
Any suggestions on how to proceed? Pointers to the right documentation are all that I think that I need.

One simple alternative is to make a compressed image with Clonezilla. You can recover a 'cloned copy' from the compressed image using Clonezilla. See also this link. - But there are probably better ways if you want to recover from a daily backup.

My basic reason for doing this is to simplify the complexity of configuring a highly complex system after Ubuntu (re)installation. Backup/recovery is a separate issue.

Then I think that the Clonezilla method (to store two or three compressed images (and replace the oldest one sequentially) in an external drive or on a server via a local network is a good alternative). The image will contain all the configuration if you make an image of the whole device (not only the partitions but the whole drive with the partition table and boot system).
